# arrays together function foreach list on date echo

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach

#### Articles are sorted by Name but not by Date, how can i do that?

**Directory structure:**

- Blog/2019/articleDirA, Blog/2019/articleDirB,...
- Blog/2018/articleDirA, Blog/2018/articleDirB,...

**Each article directory (ex. articleB) contains these files:**

- data.php
- _counter.txt
- img/

**one of the data.php:**

```
$article = array( 
  'date' => '2019-03-01',
  'headline' => 'Hello BB!'
);
```

```php
// Determine in which directory the page is located and define the correct path
if ($section === $baseDir): $actualPath = ''; else: $actualPath = '../'; endif; // result: ../;
//////////
function BlogYear() {
  global $section;
  $NewsFeedYear = array();
  $NewsFeedYear = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir'); // Determine directories (2019: articleDirA, articleDirB ...)
  rsort($NewsFeedYear); // Sorts in reverse order: // 2019, 2018, 2017 ...
  $currentYear = basename(getcwd()); // The current year is the last dir from a path in a string (2019)
  $currentYearPath = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir'); // Determine this current year directory (articleA, articleB ...)
  natsort($currentYearPath); // Sorted in natural order, 2019
//////////
echo '<div>';
foreach($currentYearPath as $articleDir_name) {
  require $articleDir_name.'/data.php';
  echo '<article id="'.$articleDir_name.'">
        <header>Article name is: <b>'.$articleDir_name.'</b></header>
        <div>
        <p>Date: <b>'.date("d. m. Y",strtotime($article['date'])).'</b></p>
        <p>Headline: '.$article['headline'].'</p>
        <p>Counter: ';
        global $base_dir;
        $basePath = preg_replace('/lib/', '', $base_dir);
        include $basePath.$section.'/'.$currentYear.'/'.$articleDir_name.'/_counter.txt';
  echo '</p>
       <p>Link: <a href="'.$section.'/'.$currentYear.'/'.$articleDir_name.'">'.$articleDir_name.'</a></p></article>';
}
echo '</div>';
 }
}
BlogYear();
```

### Result in directory 2019

Article name is: **articleDirA**
Date: **01. 01. 2019**
Headline: Hello AA!
Counter: 45
Link: Blog/2019/articleDirA/

Article name is: **articleDirB**
Date: **01. 03. 2019**
Headline: Hello BB!
Counter: 34
Link: Blog/2019/articleDirB/

Article name is: **articleDirC**
Date: **01. 02. 2019**
Headline: Hello CC!
Counter: 67
Link: Blog/2019/articleDirC/

### Expected in directory 2019

Article name is: **articleDirB**
Date: **01. 03. 2019**
Headline: Hello BB!
Counter: 34
Link: Blog/2019/articleDirB/

Article name is: **articleDirC**
Date: **01. 02. 2019**
Headline: Hello CC!
Counter: 67
Link: Blog/2019/articleDirC/

Article name is: **articleDirA**
Date: **01. 01. 2019**
Headline: Hello AA!
Counter: 45
Link: Blog/2019/articleDirA/

> They are just sort directory names but not date from each data.php
> file

Comment: Please provide more code. We can't understand from your piece of code. Ex. we don't know what is `$article`.

Comment: hello @nmfzone, thanks for the hint. I explained the code of data.php ($ article).

Answer (score 0):

You can store all `li` in an array first where you can set date as key. After you can do `krsort` which will sort the array in descending order as per your requirement. You can check below code:

```
$articleCollection = [];
foreach($currentYearPath as $articleDir_name) {
    require $articleDir_name.'/data.php';
    $articleCollection[strtotime($article['date'])] = 'your data here';
}
krsort($articleCollection);
echo implode("<br/>", $articleCollection);
```

Here, you need to set your values in `li` format at place of "your data here". I hope this will work for you.

Thanks!!

Comment: thanks! I have now described the question in more detail; The echo consists of several html tags.